# Realtek 8111 LAN not working properly stuck on 10mbps

Tags: networking, drivers, lan, gigabit-ethernet

I've opened a MSI support query to the staff but I also wanna ask in this forum too just in case someone can save me.
The problem I have is that I've got a Cat 5E ethernet cable plugged into a gigabit switch and I know the cable works due to testing it out on my laptop but in my PC it only shows 10mbps. Ive tried lots of things such as changing the Speed and Duplex, disabling power saving mode, reinstalling drivers etc and I don't have a fix.

I sometimes do get 100mbps speeds and on two occasions i even had 1gbps speed. When i install the drivers on the motherboards support page, sometimes it goes back to 100mbps but then after a reboot or when the device restarts it goes back to 10mbps.

I have noticed now that when I use the msi site support drivers for my mobo -> uninstall them through the setup -> and then let windows install the basic driver (2015) it shows 100mbps but then when i reboot or change a setting and the device restarts it goes back to 10mbps. I can live with 100mbps but 10mbps is too slow for the work I do. I'm using a B450 Tomahawk Max Board which uses a Realtek 8111H. My bios drivers are the latest and I've got the latest Windows 10 64 Pro installed. The new MSI drivers just show 10mbps. Also disabling the device through my motherboard then re enable also sets it back to 100mbps but then after a restart same things happen.

Ive bought a PCIe Realtek 8111 card too to put in and I thought it worked but then a while later after i restarted same thing happened.

What can I do to fix this? Thanks.

B450 Tomahawk MAX (VR. 7C02v37 // 3.70 )

My issue seems the same to this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/ethernet-adapter-working-with-10mbps-instead-of/e3b5e551-e4cb-47c1-88aa-94e4fab4d55a

Comment: try a cat 6e cable

Comment: I've tried cable with different device and it works perfectly, plus the cable is routed under my carpet

Comment: What is the length of the cat5e run? You ideally want to keep it well under 100m for gigabit, despite its theoretical limits.  Also look for sources of interference, (power cables running parallel, florescent lights, microwaves, other devices with high EMF).  CAT5e is a gigabit rated standard, but not all CAT5e cables are equal. If you have any other device that is gigabit, like a small 4 port switch, plug it directly into the PC with a short patch cable and see how the PC responds. If the PC still won't give you gigabit, then you have a NIC issue.

Comment: The NIC has gigabit as on two occasions ive seen it say 1gbps link speed and it worked w my NAS server. The Cable goes from one room to my room and is about less than 100m i say